# What do I need to do next in this Rock-Paper-Scissors code?

Tags: python

I'm stuck on the last bit of this code. I don't know what to do next.

I need the game to pick a random option out of the listed options so they can battle the users pick.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
 # Rock paper Scissors Game
     # Question 1
        print("Want to play Rock Paper Scissors??")
        question1=input("Y/N: ").lower()
        
        if question1=='y':
            print('Perfect but first')
        elif question1== 'n':
            print('Sorry but your here already')
        else: print('error')
        
    # Question 2
        print('Do you know how to play??')
        question2=input("Y/N: ").lower()
        
        if question2=='y':
            print('Ok lets get started!')
        elif question2=='n':
            print('Pick 1 of the 3 options to battle my option')
            print('Rock beats scissors')
            print("Paper beats rock")
            print('Scissors beats paper')
        else:
            print('error')
        
    # Display game options
        
        
        options = ['Rock', 'Paper', "Scissors"]
        def random_choose(options):
            pick = input('Take your pick:  ')
            return pick, random.choose(options)
```

Comment: `pick = random.choice(options)`

Comment: The name of the function is `random.choice`, not `random.choose`

Answer (score 0):

Well, for this question a while loop would help the game be more dynamic, allowing the player to until the player opt-out of the game. I also integrated parts of your code into this revised one. Hope this helps

```
import random as r
game = True
print("Want to play Rock Paper Scissors??")
question1=input("Y/N: ").lower()
options = ['Rock', 'Paper', "Scissors"]
if question1=='y':
    print('Perfect but first')
    print('Do you know how to play??')
    question2=input("Y/N: ").lower()
    if question2=='y':
                print('Ok lets get started!')
    elif question2=='n':
        print('Pick 1 of the 3 options to battle my option')
        print('Rock beats scissors')
        print("Paper beats rock")
        print('Scissors beats paper')   
    while game:
        pick = input('Take your pick(rock,paper or scissors):  ')
        if pick.capitalize() in options:
            Ai = r.choice(options)
            if (pick.lower()=="scissors"and Ai.lower()=="rock") or (pick.lower()=="paper" and Ai.lower()=="scissors") or (pick.lower()=="rock" and Ai.lower()=="paper"): #this is the rules for Ai vs user input(in this case Ai wins)
                print("you lose, "+ Ai +" beats "+ pick )
            elif (pick.lower()=="rock"and Ai.lower()=="scissors") or (pick.lower()=="scissors" and Ai.lower()=="paper") or (pick.lower()=="paper" and Ai.lower()=="rock"): #this is the rules for Ai vs user input(in this case player wins)
                print("you win, "+ pick +" beats "+ Ai )
            else: # in rare cases where both are the same 
                print("it's a tie, "+pick +" draws with " +Ai)
        elif pick.lower() not in options: #if the user input is not found
            print("option was not found")
        cont = input("do you want to continue [Y/N]: ")
        if cont.lower() =="n": #opting out(user quitting statement)
            game = False
        else:
            continue
            
elif question1== 'n':
    print('Alright good bye')
```

Comment: Thank you im fairly new to coding this helped a bunch.